# Angular 4 bind select option to controller

Tags: html, angular, typescript, service, binding

I get a list of categories from my service, and i want to bind the category of my controller with the option selected in my select, what i tried:

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" [(ngModel)]="category">
        <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.getCategories()">
          {{category.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

My controller:

```
category : Category = new Category(0, '', '', 0);

constructor(private categoryservice : CategoryService) { }

ngOnInit() {
}
```

With this code i get the error:
**If ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or the form control must be defined as 'standalone' in ngModelOptions.**

But i'm not using ngModel within a form, so i don't know what could be the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a name attribute to your **`select`**

```
    <select class="form-control" name="categoryDrpDown" id="category" 
 [(ngModel)]="category">
        <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.getCategories()" [ngValue]="category">>
          {{category.name}}
        </option> 
     </select>
```

Also you need to call the method **getCategories()** inside ngOninit and use the categories array only in template.

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" [(ngModel)]="category">
        <option *ngFor="let category of categories">
          {{category?.name}}
        </option>
</select>
```

and inside component

```
category : Category = new Category(0, '', '', 0);
categories : Category[] = []
constructor(private categoryservice : CategoryService) { }

ngOnInit() {
   this.categoryservice.getCategories().subscribe((response) => {
        this.categories = response;
   });
}
```

Comment: The error dissapears, so thank you, but the variable category is "undefined" now, any toughts?

Comment: you need to use the service method inside the ngOnit and use only categories in ngFor

Comment: The array categories has the values, but still, category is undefined, the ngmodel may be not binding?

Comment: try       <option *ngFor="let category of categoryservice.getCategories()" [ngValue]="category">

Comment: No sir, it is still undefined.. altough your advice on ngInit is useful, the variable category remains undefined

Comment: What do you mean undefined?

Comment: These are the values of category: Category {id: 0, name: "", description: "", cost: 0} --- These are the default values, not the ones that has the variable that i get from the service